# Add a user to Azure subscription, when they have work and personal accounts with the same email address

Tags: azure

I have an azure subscription I wish to share with another user.

This user has a work (O365) and a personal (Microsoft ID) account, from the same email address (so they can access the partner portal etc. and O365 services).

I'd like to invite them to administer my subscription, but how do I ensure that the right account gets invited? Is there any expectation of which account they will log in from after being invited? Presumably not anyone can log in using an invite link.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the Work account was the one that got always chosen, to add as personal account you have to give the user a step-by-step:

- Add the user as guest on the Azure Active Directory as usual;
- The user will receive an invite, he cannot open it yet.

The user must:

- Open a incognito window and go to [portal.azure.com](http://portal.azure.com);
- Log in to the personal account on a tab and let it open;
- Copy the link of the 'Get Started' button on the invite e-mail;
- Paste the link on a new tab and accept to register on the directory.

Done, reload the Portal's page. :)

*You can't have other open incognito pages of the same browser, the session are shared.*

Answer (score 0):

> This user has a work (O365) and a personal (Microsoft ID) account,
>   from the same email address (so they can access the partner portal
>   etc. and O365 services).

By default, there are **no** two identical email addresses.
O365 account is account(not email address), the personal account is a email account.
After you invite the email address, just the **email address** and **email password** can login the azure portal.

> Presumably not anyone can log in using an invite link.

**No**, we should use email address and email password to login azure.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the MIcrosoft account does not host an inbox, but is registered to name@comany.com. company.com are also O365 users, meaning that the same user has two logins from the same username (email address). When the user logs in, they are promoted to select which kind of account they wish to log in as.

Comment: Does the two passwords can login email? we can share azure to a microsoft account, so we should use the email's password to login azure portal.

Comment: O365 account is an azure AD account, so it is not the Microsoft account.

Comment: How do I know which account I am inviting? I can only enter an email address, will they be able to log in using either account?

Comment: @NeilP if you want to confirm which account you are inviting, you can enter the same email address, then let the email address' onwer to test, let he use the Microsoft account password and O365' password to login the azure portal. In this way we can find which account can login azure.